# Enum type checking in Python 2.7 (enum34)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, types, enums, pycharm

I use enumerations in Python 2.7 with [enum34](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), which backports the enumerations of Python 3.4 to 2.7.

In my script I have functions which get some entry of an enumeration. Since this *may* become a multi-author project, I want to declare methods explicitly type safe:

```
def someFunction(some_enum_item):
    """
    :param some_enum_item: one entry out of my Enum SAMPLE_ENUM
    :type some_enum_item: SAMPLE_ENUM
    """
    if isinstance(some_enum_item, SAMPLE_ENUM):
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

So, I want to test against the parameter if it is really an instance of `SAMPLE_ENUM` and additionally I want to have an IDE recognizing that the function only takes entries of a specific Enum.

Is `isinstance` the right way to test if the parameter has the correct type?

How am I modelling the `:type some_enum_item:` correctly? At the moment `:type some_enum_item: SAMPLE_ENUM` just checks if the parameter is the class `SAMPLE_ENUM` rather than an item of this enumeration (hence, the IDE complains when I'm passing an entry of the enumeration to the function).

Comment: You should tag this with your IDE as the question pertains directly to it.  Python doesn't care what you have in your docstrings.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer the IDE portion of your question, but as far is the `isinstance` check -- yes, that is a correct way (and the most obvious way) to determine if the object you received is a member of the enumeration.

Another way, less obvious way, is:

```
if some_enum_item in SAMPLE_ENUM:
```

Comment: Is this a good/pythonic way (`isinstance`) to check parameter types before executing the actual function?

Comment: @ascenator: Yes, `isinstance` is the pythonic way to check things.  Whether you *should* is a different question.  :)

Comment: What do you exactly mean with whether I *should*? Is it a bad design thing? How do you check the types of function parameters?